# Sum node values towards the root node in a rooted tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

### Problem

I have a *directed rooted tree* where every node has some initial value. I would like every node's new value **to equal the sum of both it and its descendants' initial values**. I envisage this process as starting at leaf nodes and propagating values up the tree towards the root node.

By the end of the process, the root node's value should be the sum of all nodes; every other node has a lesser value accordingly; every leaf node has the value it started with (since there are no children to sum into it).

**What is the best/most elegant way to perform this process on a given graph?**

### Data Structure

Just to clarify the directed rooted tree: it is a restrict form of a directed acyclic graph, where each node has **at most** 1 parent and there is a sole designated root node which doesn't have a parent.

In my implementation each node has a reference to its parent node (null for the root node) and an array of references to its child nodes (empty for leaf nodes).

### Illustration

#### Initial tree and node values

[image]

#### Modified tree with updated node values

[image]

#### Failed attempt

My simple initial attempt starts with the leaf nodes, and for each one traverses the tree upwards, adding the running sum into its parent nodes until a bifurcating parent node is reached -- such a node is added as a candidate to begin with on the next iteration.

The problem this has is that certain bifurcating nodes can be summed into their own parent more than once, for example, if the paths from its own children to the relevant leaf nodes have a varying number of further bifurcating nodes.

```
List<Node> nodes = getLeaves();
HashSet<Node> nextNodes = new HashSet<>();

while (!nodes.isEmpty()) {

    for (Node node : nodes) {

        Node current = node;

        while (current.degree < 2) { // terminate when reach bifurcating parent node
            current.parent.value += current.value;
            current = current.parent;
        }

        if (current.parent != null) { // skip root node
            nextNodes.add(current.parent); // add bifurcating parent node for next iteration
        }

    }
    nodes = new ArrayList<Node>(nextNodes);
    nextNodes.clear();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered recursion? For each node, its value is added to the value of its children. I.e., `evaluate(node) := value + evaluate(each child)`. This seems conceptually much simpler than starting at the leaves and trying to work your way backward. The recursive calls will manage this relationship for you.

Comment: Lol, you're right. For some reason I thought recursion would only work when propagating downwards from the root, and not upwards.